# How many people depend on food banks worldwide?

Tags: food

A large amount of edible food is wasted by households (corresponding to unsustainable behaviours) that could potentially be diverted to food banks. I am interested in the potential of people who could be served by surplus food. Aside this background, are there any recent studies on the number of people worldwide who depend on food donations?

Comment: Could you give some context on how this is about sustainable living, rather than politics?

Comment: A large amount of edible food is wasted by households (representing an unsustainable lifestyle) that could potentially be diverted to food banks. I am interested in the potential of people served by surplus food.

Comment: food banks are generally not set up to accept perishable items. This is a shame for the recipients, who don't get enough fresh unprocessed food as a result, and for the waste of all that perishable material.

Comment: Yes, you're right under current legislation. My estimate would be a possible scenario.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This article is from april 2015, it says that more than 1 million people used food banks, but that is not the same as being complete depended 
to food banks, hopes it helps a little
[More than 1 million people used food banks last year](https://fullfact.org/economy/more-1-million-people-used-food-banks-last-year-s-not-what-evidence-shows/)

Comment: No, that's not what the article says. The whole article is about how the evidence does **not** support the claim that more than 1 million people used food banks.

Comment: The linked article is interesting, but I agree with EnergyNumbers. In the article DEFRA is quoted: "*It is impossible at present to give an accurate estimate of the numbers of people fed by food aid providers in the UK, in total or on a regular basis (monthly or annually).*"